# Select from one database , insert to another - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to basicly copy data from one database to another (just some of them) what i need is to:

- take data from old database `SELECT name, lastname, email, phone FROM codexworld.person WHERE id="544"`
- insert that values to another table `INSERT INTO legaljobs.candidates (name, lastname, email, phone) VALUES ( name , lastname, email, phone)`

What I did try is:

```
INSERT INTO legaljobs.candidates (name, lastname, email, phone)
VALUES (SELECT name, lastname, email, phone FROM codexworld.person WHERE id="544")
```

unfortunately this throw me an error on SQL syntax. Please can somebody advise how can I do this really simple?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Insert Into from one Database in another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22912167/mysql-insert-into-from-one-database-in-another)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this query:

```
INSERT INTO legaljobs.candidates (name, lastname, email, phone)
SELECT name, lastname, email, phone FROM codexworld.person WHERE id="544"
```

Comment: Hi @Aman Aggarwai, thanks for answer unfortunatately it throw error: #1054 - Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'

Comment: then please check, which table doesn't have this column and use the correct column name..

Comment: you are right, thanks :), will mark this as correct answer as soon as I will be able to