# MYSQL Replace entire table with another one

Tags: mysql

I am trying to achieve this.
Say I have a two databases  - db1 , db2.
They each have a table called tb , the table structure is the same for both however, the records are different.
Is there any elegant way I can replace all records inside db2.tb with the records from db1.tb.
I think I can achieve this with php , but I`m looking for an elegant way.

Comment: Just blindly replace the records, or do some fields determine/allow you to decide which data should be replaced? eg: replacing matching ID's etc... Are there constraints on the tables? Indexes that are likely to require a table rebuild? Define "elegant way"...

Comment: I think OP wants an in db solution rather than do it thru PHP. @nikksan Did you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22912167/mysql-insert-into-from-one-database-in-another

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can TRUNCATE (if you want to remove all existing data in db2), then INSERT:

```
TRUNCATE db2.tb;
INSERT INTO db2.tb SELECT * FROM db1.tb;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can drop and create via select

```
 DROP Table  db2.your_table ;

 Create table db2.your_table
 select * from db1.your_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sql to truncate one table and then insert the data from the other table into it.

Put it into a transaction to keep it safe. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-transactions.html

```
TRUNCATE test.stuff;
INSERT INTO test.stuff SELECT * FROM testdb.stuff;
```