# How to transfer data FROM first database to another database?

Tags: mysql

I'm currently facing this issue of transferring data. I have refer one of the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22912167/mysql-insert-into-from-one-database-in-another) found on stackoverflow. I following but it not work. Following is my query, if any wrong please correct me.

```
INSERT
INTO
  smsrouter.carrier_account(carrier_name,is_hlr_query_account)
VALUES(nickname,0)
SELECT
  nickname
FROM
  routeinfopanel.route_list;
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO
    smsrouter.carrier_account(carrier_name, is_hlr_query_account)
SELECT nickname, 0
FROM routeinfopanel.route_list;
```

See official [**doc**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) here.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need  `VALUES` for insert select

```
INSERT INTO  smsrouter.carrier_account(carrier_name,is_hlr_query_account)
SELECT nickname,0 
FROM  routeinfopanel.route_list;
```