# How do i merge two databases in MariaDB (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Okay so if i were to make a clone of **Database A** and name it **Database B** and made some changes unto **Database B** which i later want to make unto **Database A** while **Database A** also has some newly inserted rows and tables unto it. How would i be able to only make the changes I've done unto **Database B** to **Database A** without entirely wiping out the newly inserted data on **Database A**.

I'm using MariaDB on a Linux Server, thanks.

Comment: Do the changes consist of only new, inserted rows? Or do the changes include updates to old rows? Are the changes potentially conflicting? E.g. would new rows in the two databases occupy the same primary key values? This would typically be the case if you're inserting new rows into the same tables in the two databases.

Answer (score -1):

Try this it may help you

```
USE [mydb1]
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.mytable1 (
 column1
,column2
,column3
,column4
 )
 SELECT 
 column1
,column2
,column3
,column4
 FROM [mydb2].dbo.mytable2 
 WHERE EXIST NOT (
   SELECT 1 FROM mydb2.dbo.mytable1 c 
   WHERE c.column1 = column1 ... 
   AND Any other column
 )
```

for a MYSQL syntaxe of insert from another database you can see
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22912226/4388228)

Comment: using this you can generate a script that manages your database

Comment: This is SQL Server syntax, not nearly valid for MariaDB or MySQL.

Comment: Is not about the syntax is about the IDEA @dbdemon