# C++ MySQL Connector Multiple Databases

Tags: c++, mysql

I connect and transform some table data in `db1`. Further down I want to send that data to a table in a different database `db2`.

```
MYSQL* conn;
conn = mysql_init(0);
conn = mysql_real_connect(conn, "localhost", "root", "password", "db1", 3306, NULL, 0);

if (conn) {
        ...
        // transform data

        // Connect to "db2" and insert data into table
```

Do I need to use `CLIENT_MULTI_RESULTS` when establishing a connection? Or create a new `conn`?

Comment: Is db2 in the same mysql instance as db1?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out. Just creating another variable and calling it later worked.

```
MYSQL* conn;
MYSQL* conn2;
conn = mysql_init(0);
conn2 = mysql_init(0);
conn = mysql_real_connect(conn, "localhost", "root", "password", "db1", 3306, NULL, 0);
conn2 = mysql_real_connect(conn2, "localhost", "root", "password", "db2", 3306, NULL, 0);

...

if(conn)
{ 
    puts("CONN CONNECTION SUCCESSFUL")
    ...        
    if(conn2)
    {
        puts("CONN2 CONNECTION SUCCESSFUL")
        ...
```

Comment: If the two databases are in  single mysql instance, then you only need 1 connection. Use dbnane.tablename method to access a table in the other database.

Comment: Could you provide an example please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22912167/mysql-insert-into-from-one-database-in-another