# How to copy MySQL tables of database to another database in the same server?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to make this in easy method with all records in the tables.

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22912167/mysql-insert-into-from-one-database-in-another)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829271/how-can-i-clone-an-sql-server-database-on-the-same-server-in-sql-server-2008-exp

Comment: This will copy one by one table right, What if more than 1 tables.

Comment: using PHMyAdmin, do an EXPORT and then IMPORT to a new database name

Comment: Let me try, thanks to all