# merge 2 table from 2 different database

Tags: mysql, sql, merge, union

```
INSERT INTO elearningnew.student_class_quiz SELECT * FROM elearningnew1.student_class_quiz UNION ALL SELECT * FROM elearningnew.student_class_quiz;
```

my query show error

```
Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

Unexpected token. (near "UNION ALL" at position 91)
```

can anyone help how to solve this problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Insert Into from one Database in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22912167/mysql-insert-into-from-one-database-in-another)

Comment: maybe try creating temporary table first ? or use brackets around union all ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Insert into Database.table1 (Column1, Column2) SELECT Column11, Column12 from Database2.table2;
```

My output with query:

table1:

```
EmployeeID  Name
1          Vinitha
2          Vini
```

table2:

```
CategoryId  CategoryCode    CategoryName
1             Mobile           Samsung
4             Laptop             hp
```

Query:

```
 Insert into OnlineCameraShoppingDB.Master.Categories (CategoryCode, CategoryName) SELECT EmployeeID, Name from WebApiInMvcCrud.dbo.Employee;
```

Output:

```
CategoryId  CategoryCode    CategoryName
9            1               Vinitha
10           2               Vini
```