# How insert in table from another database MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

**I have a table in a hosting I want to communicate with it remotely through my localhost, but I can't reference that I want the table from that database how do I do that?**

*im using php *

```
<?php

// Create connection

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','contador');
$conn2 = mysqli_connect('hostingIP', 'userIp', 'userPass');
$tableName='counter';
$dbname2='dbHosting';
$result = mysqli_query($conn2,$dbname2);

$sql = "INSERT INTO tab2 (Data,price) VALUES ( now(),(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $result.$tableName WHERE DATE(Data)= CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 0 DAY))";

?>
```

Comment: you can refer to this Issue ->

Comment: This one :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22912167/mysql-insert-into-from-one-database-in-another

Comment: I use ssh tunnels for such things _if_ your hosting provider offers such option. Wireguard also is a good option _if_ yout hosting provider allows to install such thing.

Comment: @franckgarcon I doubt that the OP has network access to connect to the mysql server the hosting service offers from his local network.

Comment: @Franck Gracon Error: INSERT INTO counter.results (Data,Acessos) VALUES ( now(),(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dnhosting.counter WHERE DATE(Data)= CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 0 DAY))
Table 'dbHosting.contador' doesn't exist

Answer (score -2):

1. Make an export script in localhost.
2. Trigger it regularly via cron jobs.
3. Include FTP credentials to upload it to your server.
4. Make an import script in your server.
5. Trigger it regularly via cron jobs.

Thank me later :)

Comment: You do not know if the OP uses the old and totally outdated FTP protocol to access that hosting environment.

Comment: And you also don't know if such asynchronous solution is suitable for the OP.

Comment: The answer is vague but it might point the OP in the right direction. At least it gives him some possibilities to try. I think it's an appropriate answer to the question, which is also vague.